# rosbag pause Marker disappears

Tags: ros, rosbag, marker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

We have a node that publishes a set of markers. Those markers are part of sensor detections. So they can appear or disappear while the node is running, which is normal.

Now after doing a recording, we would like to pause the bag. When rosbag is on pause, all markers disappear. Programmatically all markers have a `lifetime`, such that they can be automatically removed. Is this the reason why markers also removed while on pause?

If yes, how is the right approach to solve this issue? Do I need to remove markers manually and not rely on `lifetime`?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275400/rosbag-pause-marker-disappears/) by [tanasis](https://answers.ros.org/users/29349/tanasis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 97 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Programmatically all markers have a `lifetime`, such that they can be automatically removed. Is this the reason why markers also removed while on pause?

yes, most likely. `rosbag` is no magic, it essentially just replays message traffic it has recorded. (Interactive) Markers are also just messages, so if those messages are played back by `rosbag` and they contain a `lifetime` setting other than `ros::Duration()` they will disappear.

> If yes, how is the right approach to solve this issue? Do I need to remove markers manually and not rely on `lifetime`?

Well. Technically if you pause `rosbag play` I would expect time to also 'freeze', so perhaps markers with a timeout should not disappear. But that will depend on whether you are asking `rosbag` to also publish the clock.

If they still disappear with `--clock` after you've paused playback, that would perhaps be a bug and should be reported.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [barney@work](https://answers.ros.org/users/60886/barney@work/) on 2020-10-13**:
Setting `rosparam set /use_sim_time true` sets the `use_sim_time` parameter worked for me

The links are as given below

- http://wiki.ros.org/Clock
- http://wiki.ros.org/rosparam#rosparam_set